# How do I create a new variable using observations from old variables?

Tags: r

I have a dataset where the education variable is numerically coded from 1 - 18, with each number representing a different educational qualification.  I want to create a new variable where there would be five categories, ranging from no qualifications to postgraduate. In each of these five categories I want to combine a few of the old educational qualifications into one. For example I would like 1,2,3 = Secondary education.

Comment: I think https://community.rstudio.com/t/case-when-why-not/2685/3 is a good read for deciding on a method to implement, should you opt for a tidyverse option.

Answer (score 2):

Using some `ifelse` statements can get you there.

An answer using the `dplyr` package:

```
yourdata%>%
    mutate(New_Category=ifelse(OldCategory %in% c(1,2,3),"Category1",
                    ifelse(OldCategory %in% c(4,7,9),"Category2",
                    ifelse(OldCategory %in% c(5,6,8),"Category3",
                    ifelse(OldCategory %in% c(10,11,12,13,14),"Category4",
                    ifelse(OldCategory %in% c(15,16,17,18),"Category5","Unknown"))))))
```

You have the flexibility here to group however you want.  Essentially, this checks if the first statement it true, and if so, puts "Category1" as the value for your new `New_Category` column.  If not, it proceeds to the next `ifelse` statement.

The last thing in the nested `ifelse` that you need is that value to put if none of the conditional checks holds true.  In the example above, I used "Uknown".

I'd recommend avoiding the inclination to skip explicitly naming the conditions for "Category5" and using it as the "if none of the other things above is true" value, as sometimes folks will do.  If you do this, you run the risk of blanks or out-of-range values getting converted to "Category 5", and thus won't be able to do a solid error-check should you choose to count the number of records by category or some such.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option for base R. It is less elegant than Pake's dplyr solution, but it does the trick and is perhaps a little easier to understand if you are not yet familiar with tidyverse language which can be pretty different from base R.

```
##Creating some Fake Data##
Ed_1<-c(1:18) #Numeric Education Variable
Ed_cat<-c("No_High_School_Diploma","GED_or_High_School_Diploma", "Some_College", "College_Degree", "PostGraduate") #Categorical Education Variable
ED<-data.frame(Education_Level = sample(Ed_1, 100, replace = TRUE)) #A random example dataset

##Creating a new column, and adding categorical data##
ED[,"Education_Group"]<-NULL
ED$Education_Group[ED$Education_Level %in% c(1:3)]<-Ed_cat[1]
ED$Education_Group[ED$Education_Level %in% c(4:7)]<-Ed_cat[2]
ED$Education_Group[ED$Education_Level %in% c(8:11)]<-Ed_cat[3]
ED$Education_Group[ED$Education_Level %in% c(12:15)]<-Ed_cat[4]
ED$Education_Group[ED$Education_Level %in% c(16:18)]<-Ed_cat[5]

##Viewing the results##
ED$Education_Group
```

The trick is to use the square brace syntax which in R means "select" and then assigning a new value using the assignment arrow.

Breaking down this line of code

```
ED$Education_Group[ED$Education_Level %in% c(16:18)]<-Ed_cat[5]
```

`ED$Education_Group` means "select the Education_Group column as a vector"
`[ED$Education_Level %in% c(16:18)]` means "where the corresponding value of the Education_Level in the same row is in the set {16, 17, 18}"
`<-Ed_cat[5]` means "assign these values the fifth element of the Ed_cat vector"

In plain English the whole line of code mean "Any Education level between 16 and 18 should be assigned 'Post-Graduate' as its Education Group."
Take Care,
-Sean

Answer (score 1):

Try `case_when` function like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(new_education = case_when(
      education %in% c(1:3) ~ "Category 1",
      education %in% c(4:6) ~ "Category 2",
      education %in% c(7:9) ~ "Category 3",
      education %in% c(10:12) ~ "Category 4",
      education %in% c(13:15) ~ "Category 5",
      education %in% c(16:18) ~ "Category 6",
      TRUE ~ "No category"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the easiest way to assign values to category clusters is with the `cut` function. E.g.

```
breaks <- c(-Inf, 3, 7, 11, 14, Inf)
labels <- c("No_High_School_Diploma","GED_or_High_School_Diploma", "Some_College", "College_Degree", "PostGraduate")
df$cats <- cut(df$education, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)
```

Note that the number of breaks requires n+1 the number of labels